# Move FrameLayout from CardView to overlap it

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

I'm trying to do this type of layout, the thing is that I cant displace the FrameLayout above the image like this image

[image]

### Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/premiofondo"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/blanco">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="1º Premio"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="Primer premio \n Orden de compra \n $100.000"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### My output

[image]

I want to displace **1º premio** to be like the first image, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ConstraintLayout`, move your `FrameLayout` outside of `CardView`, and set `FrameLayout`'s elevation as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/premiofondo"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Primer premio \n Orden de compra \n $100.000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/blanco"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:outlineProvider="none"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card_view"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1º Premio"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that `android:outlineProvider="none"` makes it so that the elevation shadow will not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

*There are many ways to do this. Take a new frame layout inside linear layout and also move out your frame layout from card view. Try this...*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/premiofondo"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Primer premio \n Orden de compra \n $100.000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/blanco">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1º Premio"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </FrameLayout>


  </FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```